# Jquery toggle(), display property

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

http://jsfiddle.net/nP9SP/5/

I have my code in the fiddle above, after toggle, I am trying to see the display property and remove a css class, but it always shows 'block' with my alert, but eventually the css class is changed to 'none' why is the lag here? any idea?

`alert($('div#main').css('display'));`

Comment: In your fiddle you are finding the `<p>` elements `$( "p" ).toggle( );` but then you are asking for the display property of the containing `<div>` - which you aren't changing.

Comment: Since you are using `slideToggle` which animates the show/hide the animation is happening "asynchronously" and so the state isn't actually changing right away, even though the duration is 0. `slideToggle` does take a callback [https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) and so you could put the code that follows the toggle inside the callback. [http://jsfiddle.net/nP9SP/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/nP9SP/6/)

Comment: @lemieuxster: yes, you are right, toggle does not have this issue, but slideToggle does. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Hey i got ans to your question as change your html with given below and see it will run....

```
<body>
<button>Toggle 'em</button>
    <div id="main">
<p>Hiya</p>
<p>Such interesting text, eh?</p>
    </div>
    <span class="arr hid">0</span>
<script>
$( "button" ).live('click',function() {
$( "div#main" ).slideToggle( 'medium', function() {
    if ($('div#main').is(':visible'))
        {

            alert($('div#main').css('display'));
             $('span.arr').addClass("hid");
    }
    else{
           alert($('div#main').css('display')+" hello");
             $('span.arr').removeClass("hid"); 
        }
    });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Because that is not setting the `display` property to `none` for that `div` you have to use `.toggle()` method on `div` instead:

```
$('div#main').toggle(); // toggle the div instead
alert($('div#main').css('display')); // its none now
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `display` value of your `p` elements, since that's what you're using `toggle()` on:

```
alert($('p').css('display'));
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nP9SP/4/).